# Подскажите, пожалуйста, "уверенности в успехе" — это два дополнения или одно?

Tags: синтаксис, дополнение

Полное предложение: "Игроки полны уверенности в победе".

Comment: Устина, определитесь: уверенности *в успехе* (в шапке) или *в победе* (в предложении)?